# Difficulties using Postgresql's EXTRACT tool via function call

Tags: postgresql, date

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Postgresql `EXTRACT` function to convert a given `date_variable` into its equivalent day of the week. I understand that it will convert the `date_variable` into a numbering from 0 - 6 (0 is Sunday, 6 is Saturday etc)

I've created a simple table to test my queries. Here I will attempt to convert the `start_date` into its DOW equivalent.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test(
  start_date    date PRIMARY KEY,
  end_date      date
);

INSERT INTO test (start_date, end_date) VALUES ('2021-03-31', '2021-03-31'); -- Today (wed), hence 3
INSERT INTO test (start_date, end_date) VALUES ('2021-03-30', '2021-03-30'); -- Yesterday (tues), hence 2
INSERT INTO test (start_date, end_date) VALUES ('2021-03-29', '2021-03-29'); -- Day before (mon), hence 1
```

If I were to run the query below

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(DOW FROM t.start_date)) AS day FROM test t;
```

It works fine, and returns the result as intended (returns a single column table with values (3, 2, 1) respectively.)

However, when I attempt to write a function to return the exact same query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_day()
RETURNS TABLE (day integer) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT (EXTRACT(DOW FROM t.start_date)) as day 
        FROM test t;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM get_day(); -- throws error "structure of query does not match function result type"
```

I get an error instead. I cant seem to find the issue and don't know what is causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`extract()` returns a `double precision` value, but your function is declared to return an integer. You need to cast the value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_day()
RETURNS TABLE (day integer) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM t.start_date)::int as day 
        FROM test t;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But you don't really need PL/pgSQL for this, a `language SQL` function would also work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_day()
RETURNS TABLE (day integer) AS $$
  SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM t.start_date)::int as day 
  FROM test t;
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql
stable;
```

As you are not passing any parameters, I would actually use a view for this:

```
create or replace view day_view
AS
SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM t.start_date)::int as day 
FROM test t;
```

Answer (score 0):

The extract function returns values of type double precision.

You declare result to be integer.

You should cast the result of EXTRACT to integer:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_day()
RETURNS TABLE (day integer) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM t.start_date)::integer as day 
        FROM test t;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```